# Code an ASCII tab into QR barcode for PHP so MS Excel can read it

Tags: php, excel, qr-code

I have been using PHP QR Code (http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) to create QR barcodes.  Each barcode contains several different pieces of information that I concatenate into a single string.  The reason I am doing this is because the label I have to print on is too small to make separate barcodes for each piece of information.

```
$PartNumber = '12345';
$UIN = 'ABCD';
$IMEI = 00001;
$WHSE = 'AAA';
$Barcode = $PartNumber.$UIN.$IMEI.$WHSE;

QRcode::png($Barcode, 'Barcode.png');
```

This part works perfectly fine.  I print the barcode and then scan it into Excel and I get a string that reads '12345ABCD00001AAA'.  What I want to be able to do is put the ASCII code for the Tab button in between each variable so that when I scan the barcode into Excel, each variable will be in a different column.

```
$PartNumber = '12345';
$UIN = 'ABCD';
$IMEI = 00001;
$WHSE = 'AAA';
$Barcode = $PartNumber.'\09'.$UIN.'\09'.$IMEI.'\09'.$WHSE;

QRcode::png($Barcode, 'Barcode.png');
```

So the result would be Cell A1 = '12345', B1 = 'ABCD', C1 = '00001', D1 = 'AAA'.

However, when I scan the barcode into Excel the whole string is placed in cell A1. I can hear Excel dinging as if it doesn't like the ASCII value and then seems to ignore it. I would prefer not to have to use code in Excel to separate the string based on a delimiter that I add.

Does anyone know how I can get each variable into it's own column, or if it's even possible to do?

Comment: Why not use the ascii code for tab then? (using [chr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)) `$Barcode = $PartNumber.chr(9).$UIN.chr(9).$IMEI.chr(9).$WHSE;` or even simply `$Barcode = $PartNumber."\t".$UIN."\t".$IMEI."\t".$WHSE;`

Comment: So the weird thing is, when I do this, Excel seems to interpret the chr(9) as italicize.

Comment: never used that library, but a lot don't like actual special characters and have special (possibly url) encoded variants eg %09 instead of '/t' or chr(9) - just noticed that you've probably done that anyway! ignore me

Comment: The barcode scanner might be replacing the tab character before transmitting the decoded value to the computer. Try looking in the manual for your scanner to see if there is an option to switch this off (for Symbol scanners, look for a "Function Key Mapping" option)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.  I got it to work.  I Enabled the Function Key Mapping and then used chr(9) and it works great. So it appears that the Function Key Mapping was the issue.